# this json code is displaying no result

Tags: php, json

I am returning a json array and trying to receive it in controller but it displaying no results
Here is my model:

```
if ((!empty($_FILES["FlMediaImage"])) &&($_FILES["FlMediaImage"]["error"] == 0)) {
        $mdImgName = $_FILES["FlMediaImage"]["name"];
            $ext = substr($mdImgName, strpos($mdImgName, '.') + 1);
            $mdImgName = 'adsmind_media_' . md5(uniqid(time(), true)) . '.' . $ext;
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["FlMediaImage"]["tmp_name"], ROOT . "/images/temp/" . $mdImgName);
        }
        $jsonArry = array(
            "image_id" => 0,
            "image_name" => $result->$mdImgName
        );
        return json_encode(array('result' => $jsonArry));
```

My controller is:

```
$imageJSON = json_decode($modObj->saveMediaImage());
$imageID = $imageJSON->result->image_id;
$imageName = $imageJSON->result->image_name;
```

Comment: can you please print this $modObj->saveMediaImage() and let me know the results.

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: $modObj->saveMediaImage() return json_encode(array('result' => $jsonArry)); ? Right?

Comment: @Praveenkalal {"result":{"image_id":0,"image_name":null}}

Comment: NO error @SureshKamrushi

Answer (score 0):

Your result is null in both vars.. $imageID and $imageName...
Change some values, like

```
$jsonArry = array("image_id" => '0', "image_name" => 'some_name');
```

and you will see result.

Answer (score 0):

its working

```
$arr= json_decode( '{"result":{"image_id":0,"image_name":null}}',FALSE);
echo $arr->result->image_id;
```

Can you try with it

```
$imageJSON = json_decode($modObj->saveMediaImage());
$imageID = $imageJSON->result->image_id;
$imageName = (isset($imageJSON->result->image_name) && !empty($imageJSON->result->image_name))?$imageJSON->result->image_name:'';
```